# Twitter Bootstrap - How to handle form-horizontal with multiple inputs on the same line and multiple screen sizes?

Tags: css, asp.net-mvc, twitter-bootstrap

I'm developing an application that has at least 30+ input fields.  I would like to use `form-horizontal` and have my labels to the left of my input fields.  I run into an issue when I have multiple label/textboxes on the same line.  For example, I'm trying to fit City (and its textbox), State (and its dropdown), and Zip Code (and its textbox).  It looks fine on a widescreen, but labels begin to overlap other inputs when the screen is reduced to non-widescreen (and worse when at tablet screen size).

How can I avoid this?  Should each label/input combination be its own `span4` within the same row-fluid?  Should I be trying to fit all within a single div of `span12`?

I've tried to find examples, but every one that I've found doesn't use form-horizontal and isn't very complex.  I'm using Bootstrap 2.3.2.

Code:

```
<div class="row-fluid">
    <div class="span4">
        @Html.LabelFor(m => m.PrimaryCompanyAddress.City, new {@class = "control-label", @for = "PrimaryCompanyAddress_City"})
        <div class="controls">
            @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.PrimaryCompanyAddress.City)
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="span4">
        @Html.LabelFor(m => m.PrimaryCompanyAddress.State, new {@class = "control-label"})
        <div class="controls">
            @Html.StateDropDownListFor(m => m.PrimaryCompanyAddress.State, new {@class = "input-medium"})
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="span4">
        @Html.LabelFor(m => m.PrimaryCompanyAddress.Zip, new {@class = "control-label"})
        <div class="controls">
            @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.PrimaryCompanyAddress.Zip, new {@class = "input-mini"})
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: This issue is better explained with a code sample. Do you have one?

Answer (score 0):

Your main problem is Bootstrap 2. It was not built to be responsive, while Bootstrap 3 was. If you can upgrade (which admittedly is non-trivial), then that would be your best bet. Short of that, you'll need to handle it manually with breakpoints. For example, let's say your form looks fine until the screen width falls below 1024 pixels, then you would add something akin to the following to your stylesheet:

```
@media (max-width: 1024px) {
    .input-medium {
        max-width: (whatever)px;
    }
    /* continue tweaking each element until everything fits and looks right */
}
```

Then, you would continue to scale down your screen width until it breaks again, and then add another breakpoint along the same lines.